# Ng-animate not working in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm working on a mobile app using Phonegap and AngularJS. I'm currently just developing and testing on a local wampserver for ease.

I'm trying to get `ng-animate` working on my `ng-view`, in order to animate changing of views similar to mobile apps. Any guide I follow or any code I use doesn't seem to do anything at all. No errors or animations.

Here's my current ng-view code:

```
    <body ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'view-enter', leave: 'view-leave'}"></body>
```

And here's my current CSS for that ng-animate:

```
.view-enter, .view-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.view-enter {
  opacity:0;
  left:100px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.view-enter.view-enter-active {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.view-leave {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  opacity:1;
}
.view-leave.view-leave-active {
  left:-100px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

And yet, no errors or animations at all. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or how I can get animations working? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm what version of AngularJS you're using? Animation via ngAnimate is only available in the unstable versions, and not in the 1.0.7 version that is the latest stable one.

Comment: @MichalCharemza wow, you're right... I was on 1.0.7. Just upgraded to 1.1.5 and the animations worked instantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was pointed out thanks to Michal Charemza... I was on the latest stable version of AngularJS, 1.0.7, and ng-animate is only in the unstable versions. I downloaded 1.1.5 from [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/) and the above code for animations worked instantly.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Needs to be tweaked a bit in terms of how the animation feels, but the concept seems to work.